# Swift UITableView GoTo Other Row When access tableView.reloadData() in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have problem, when I open a `UITableViewController` from other `UIViewController` with `scrollToRow` in `viewDidAppear()` like this, it's in order to go to specified row when `UITableViewController` opened.

```
class ReadingBook: UITableViewController {

 // blablabla
// blablabla

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: identifierHeader, bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifierHeader)
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: identifierCell, bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifierCell)
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
            tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
            tableView.allowsSelection = true
            tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
            tableView.bounces = false

            generateDatas()


     }

    // blablabla
    //blablabla

     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 10, section: 0)
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .top)
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: false)
     }

     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          super.viewWillAppear(animated)

          tableView.reloadData()
     }

}
```

And then the problem is, this for example: 
When I in `ReadingBook` page in position view is at row **10**, and I go to `MySettingPage` to setting font color of label in row book, etc. When I go back to `ReadingBook` page with `navigationController` it will auto scroll to row **16**. But when I remove line `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear` it will normal, the row will show in last position before I go to `MySettingPage`, example before I go to MySettingPage the row position is **10**, so when I back is in row **10**. But when I remove `tableView.reloadData()` from `viewWillAppear` the font color not change when I set to other color from `MySettingPage`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add the photo to describe more about what is color problem? But I think the answer with DispatchQueue is correct in this case if you need to reload tableview

Comment: make scroll in table delegate func didSelectRowAtIndexPath, remove tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .top) from viewDidAppear